# como quitar un elemnto del array en php usando un boto o con una equita <a>

Tags: php

Buenas, necesito saber como quitar un elemento del array de un bucle for en php usando el unset() peor que este se ejecute cuando de click en un boton o una etiqueta a> si alguien me da una solución

---

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['p']; 
$_SESSION['contador']++;


}

if (isset($_GET['c'])){
    $_SESSION['cantidad'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['c'];
}

include '../conexion/server.php';

for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION['contador']; $i++){
//echo "producto:".$_SESSION['producto'][$i]."-".$_GET['c'][$i]."<br>";

        $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


            $cab = $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i+1];
            $total = $fila['Precio']*$cab;
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
                echo '<center><td>';
                echo '<center><input type=number name=ja class="la ma" value='.$cab.'></center>';
                echo '</td></center>';
                echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<form method=get>';
                echo '<input type=hidden name=ya value='.$i.'>';
                echo '<button type=submit name="boton_borrar">borrar</button>';
                echo '</form>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';


                    if(isset($_GET['boton_borrar'])){

                                $v = $_GET['ya'];

                            unset($_SESSION['contador'][$v]);


                    }

        }


}

?>
```

---

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['p']; 
$_SESSION['contador']++;


}

if (isset($_GET['c'])){
    $_SESSION['cantidad'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['c'];
}

include '../conexion/server.php';
```

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar que tipo de elemento o puedes copiar parte de tu código para poder ayudarte, Gracias

Comment: Hola @JosePMoya , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

una solución simple y sencilla para lo que querés hacer, puede ser la siguiente...

En la etiqueta  del HTML, le podés agregar el atributo onclick con una instrucción de JavaScript para que ejecute un PHP externo. Si quieres que ese PHP se ejecute en la misma ventana, deberías usar "location.href", mientras que si quieres que se ejecute en una pestaña o ventana aparte, deberías usar "window.open".

Ejemplo con "location.href":

```
<a onclick="location.href='borrar.php?borrar=valor'" href="#">Borrar</a>
```

Ejemplo con "window.open":

```
<a onclick="window.open('borrar.php?borrar=valor')" href="#">Borrar</a>
```

También puedes usar Ajax de JQuery para establecer un evento "onclick" en un elemento "`<script>`" para que ejecute una petición de manera asíncrona de forma tal que no te vayas de la pestaña, e incluso puedes hacer modificaciones FrontEnd dentro de ese mismo evento.

Ejemplo:

```
<script>
    $("a.borrar").on("click", function(){
        url = "borrar.php";
        data = { borrar : "valor" };
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (e) {
                alert("valor eliminado!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="borrar" href="#">Borrar</a>
```

Aclaro que ésto es para ejecutar el archivo PHP al hacer click sobre una etiqueta "`<a>`" como dijiste en la pregunta. Lo que quieras hacer en el PHP ya pasa a ser idea tuya cómo lo quieras eliminar.

Espero que esta te sea útil, saludos!

Comment: listo....lo que pasa es que no se como hacer que la información que esta en el bucle se elimine si pongo borrar en el 1er dato ese se borre, peor cunado pongo unset me sale un error diciendo que el offset:0 y no se como realizar una fomra d eborrar la informacion y el dato del array en el bucle for php